# Need to count records and group count by date on Oracle

Tags: oracle-10g, count, oracle-sql-developer, group-by

I have a table like the following

```
   ID                created    sent    type
-----------------------------------------------------
0001463583000051783  31-JUL-12  1   270
0081289563000051788  01-AUG-12  1   270
0081289563000051792  01-AUG-12  1   270
0081289563000051791  01-AUG-12  1   270
0081289563000051806  01-AUG-12  1   270
0001421999000051824  06-AUG-12  1   270
0001421999000051826  06-AUG-12  1   270
0001464485000051828  06-AUG-12  1   270
0082162128000051862  09-AUG-12  2   278
0082162128000051861  09-AUG-12  2   278
0022409222082910259  09-AUG-12  3   278
```

I would like to have the following for output

```
created     Count
---------------------
31-JUL-12   1
01-AUG-12   4
06-AUG-12   3
09-AUG-12   3
```

How hard would it be to accomplish this using SQL Developer on Oracle 10g?

I have tried several queries to generate such a table and in the end it does not group the count by date, just gives me a '1' for the count when we average 5000-10000 transactions daily. I'm probably overcomplicating it. But I would like something simple where I can pull the amount of transactions on a daily basis within a date range.

Comment: How about you post the queries you've tried that didn't work? I wouldn't want to suggest a query only for you to reply that you've already tried it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, your query would be something like this:

```
select created, count(*) CreatedCount
from yourtable
group by created
order by created;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/916a7/4)

Or if you have a time associated with the date, you can use `TRUNC`:

```
select trunc(created), count(*) CreatedCount
from yourtable
group by trunc(created)
order by trunc(created);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6e81/2)

Comment: I'm guessing the "created" dates also have a time part, and some form of `trunc`ing would help the OP.

Comment: @Mat good point, updated with query that includes `trunc`

Comment: Nice solution! Didnt realize there is a trunc function for Oracle.